# Disabling window resizing or mouse dragging

Tags: windows, gui, mouse

I'm on Windows. Since I always prefer the default appearances of GUI, I want **to prevent accidental resizing (e.g. window resizing, column resizing)**.
**Any tools for disabling resizing? Or by indirectly disabling mouse dragging function (which is a less preferred solution)?**

Thanks. I tend to restore the system every time such unwanted UI modifications are made, faithfully stuck on the defaults (of the quantitative settings such as for UI).

Comment: In general or for a specific window?

Comment: @Cornelius In general. Want to disable any resizing function.

Comment: Somewhat related - https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings-winpc/how-to-completely-disable-windows-automatically/659b3600-36f7-4be9-858b-6ed785ca6787